# How do I calculate integral of exp(a*x**2+b*x+c)?

Tags: python, sympy

So i want to calculate integral of `exp(-ax^2-bx-c)` assuming that `a>0, b>0, c>0` using sympy.

So i done this:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c')
assumptions = Q.real(a), Q.positive(a), \
              Q.real(b), Q.positive(b), \
              Q.real(c), Q.positive(c)

with assuming(*assumptions):
    expression = exp(-a*x**2 - b*x - c)
    ans = integrate(expression, (x, -oo, oo))
    ans = simplify(ans)

print(str(ans).replace(',', ',\n\n'))
```

And i get this:

```
Piecewise((sqrt(pi)*(erf(b/(2*sqrt(a))) + erfc(b/(2*sqrt(a))) + 1)*exp(-c + b**2/(4*a))/(2*sqrt(a)),

 (Abs(arg(a)) < pi/2) | ((Abs(arg(a)) <= pi/2) & (2*Abs(arg(b)) < pi) & (Abs(2*arg(b) + 2*pi) < pi))),

 (Integral(exp(-a*x**2 - b*x - c),

 (x,

 -oo,

 oo)),

 True))
```

But i know, that answer must be:

```
sqrt(pi/a) * exp(b**2/(4*a) - c)
```

As i think, assuming isnt working, so i tried this:

```
from sympy import *

a = symbols('a')
assumptions = [ Q.positive(a) ]
with assuming(*assumptions):
    print(ask(Q.is_true(a > 0)))
```

And the answer is:

```
None
```

And this is very strange. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 0 is positive. So if you want any symbol to be nonzero, you have to set it to `nonzero=True` in symbol creation.

Comment: Actually wolframalpha agrees on the solution that you get from Sympy: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp%28-a*x**2-b*x-c%29

Comment: Yes, wolfram gives this answer, but only because it isnt specified that a>0,b>0,c>0

Comment: [Here](http://www.hep.upenn.edu/~johnda/Papers/GausInt.pdf) in (3) you can see almost exact formula, and answer without `erf` special function, which is not needed here.

Comment: it's actually the same result, just not simplified good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sympy documentation is confusing about this. You are trying to use the "new" assumptions system which is still experimental and is not actually used internally by sympy. You need to use the core assumptions system in which assumptions are set when creating symbols:

```
In [50]: from sympy import * 
    ...:  
    ...: x = symbols('x') 
    ...: a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c', positive=True)                                                                                           

In [51]: integrate(exp(-a*x**2 - b*x - c), (x, -oo, oo))                                                                                       
Out[51]: 
  ⎛         2                     ⎞                             
  ⎜        b                     2⎟                             
  ⎜       ───                   b ⎟                 2           
  ⎜       4⋅a    ⎛ b  ⎞        ───⎟                b            
  ⎜  π⋅b⋅ℯ   ⋅erf⎜────⎟        4⋅a⎟               ───           
  ⎜              ⎝2⋅√a⎠   π⋅b⋅ℯ   ⎟  -c       -c  4⋅a     ⎛ b  ⎞
  ⎜- ────────────────── - ────────⎟⋅ℯ     √π⋅ℯ  ⋅ℯ   ⋅erfc⎜────⎟
  ⎝         2⋅√a            2⋅√a  ⎠                       ⎝2⋅√a⎠
- ───────────────────────────────────── + ──────────────────────
                   √π⋅b                            2⋅√a
```

That result can be simplified. It looks like simplify doesn't handle erf plus erfc but we can give it a little help:

```
In [52]: integrate(exp(-a*x**2 - b*x - c), (x, -oo, oo)).simplify()                                                                            
Out[52]: 
                                        2
                                       b 
                                 -c + ───
   ⎛   ⎛ b  ⎞       ⎛ b  ⎞    ⎞       4⋅a
√π⋅⎜erf⎜────⎟ + erfc⎜────⎟ + 1⎟⋅ℯ        
   ⎝   ⎝2⋅√a⎠       ⎝2⋅√a⎠    ⎠          
─────────────────────────────────────────
                   2⋅√a                  

In [53]: integrate(exp(-a*x**2 - b*x - c), (x, -oo, oo)).simplify().rewrite(erfc)                                                              
Out[53]: 
           2
          b 
    -c + ───
         4⋅a
√π⋅ℯ        
────────────
     √a
```

Comment: Wow, that was really unexpected for me, but thanks for clear explanation!